# Notification of more than one person in a comment

Tags: feature-request

Why it is impossible to notify more than one person (by @ sign) in a comment to a post? ([example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42138/i-understand-you-vs-i-do-understand-you))

Comment: I suspect because comments are not a conversation

Answer (score 4):

Because [Jeff Atwood says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment), "there's no valid case for "I need to notify a large number of people" -- at least not one I will support by writing software for it."

Comment: Thanks! But anyway, I'm on @Koper's side in that discussion.

Comment: Two is not a large number.

Comment: @Peter Shor - It's twice the size of one! ;)